# What is the correct output of this statement?

Tags: c, printf

```
int a=9,b=6,c=3;
printf("%d%d%d");
```

I executed this in code blocks 10.05. I got some garbage values. But in a website the output was given as 3 6 9. What is the correct one?

Comment: `printf("%d%d%d");` arguments missing-- undefined behavior.

Comment: It's undefined behavior, and there are many duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

You will get garbage values, because you're not providing any arguments to the printf() call.

The correct code would be

```
printf("%d%d%d",c,b,a);
```

(to get the numbers in the order quoted)

Comment: But the "garbage" values may indeed be a, b, and c's values; the point is that what is actually printed is undefined. It may indeed be "3 6 9", but it could be anything else, as well.

Comment: True - I suppose strictly speaking the answer to the question "which is the correct output" is that it's undefined. However, I assumed that the OP wanted to know what was causing the behaviour he didn't expect rather than a technically correct but less informative response :)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill The local variables are stored in stack. So when `printf()` is invoked, it search for the _variable reference_ in that stack examining its type. But if any variable name is not provided, then it fails to map the **format specifier** with the variable name then directly fetch the value from stack in FIFO order.

Comment: That's pretty much gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

The correct one is neither of the two you described. Since no values were passed to `printf`, only the formatters, whatever was on the stack at that moment (which is undefined) is passed.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct output of this statement?

This code invokes **undefined behaviour** and so there is no correct output. The output is undefined.

The code invokes undefined behaviour because the format string you passed to `printf` requires you to pass more parameters (3) than you supplied (0).